# Show completions under the prompt in Fish

Tags: autocomplete, fish

Is there a way I can get the ultra compact auto-complete function from Zsh in Fish, so If I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it won't write me all the possibilities permanently into my terminal but underneath the prompt?

Answer (score 3):

It's [work in (good) progress](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/291) and not released yet (as of 2014-03-07), but the next version will have completion below the cursor as in `zsh`.

If you want to try it out, you can compile `fish` from source from the [github repository](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell)